# How to Extract RegEx from Pandas Dataframe and use it with re.findall

Tags: python, regex, pandas

My problem started when I stored all the RegEx expressions in a HDF5 file and then tried to extract them via pandas dataframe.

The main issue is that the RegEx expressions stored in pandas dataframe do not work correctly with `re.findall`. What made things worse is that I used Arabic Unicode in my RegEx expressions.

To simplify things, I provide the example below:

Let’s assume that we have the following text stored in a variable:

```
mytext = 'الفئران هم حيوانات غير معمرة لأن معدل استقلابهم مرتفع وضربات قلبهم سريعة'
```

And let’s have the following RegEx expression:

```
pattern_they = r'([\u0621-\u064a]+\u0647\u0645|\b\u0647\u0645)\b'
```

If we use the code `print(re.findall(pattern_they, mytext))`, we get a list of three elements:

```
['هم', 'استقلابهم', 'قلبهم']
```

Now, if we create a new pattern which includes `pattern_they` enclosed by double quote marks:

```
pattern_they_new = "r'([\u0621-\u064a]+\u0647\u0645|\b\u0647\u0645)\b'"
```

And then use this pattern in `print(re.findall(pattern_they_new, mytext))`, we get an empty list which is not correct.

The problem here is that all the RegEx expressions I extracted from the pandas dataframe are wrapped with double quote marks just like `pattern_they_new`. I did not add the double quote marks when I stored the RegEx expressions; they are added automatically when I extract them from the panda dataframe.

I tried to store the RegEx expressions without `r'…'`, but it did not work either with `re.findall`.

How can I solve this issue?

NB: this question is a follow up of another one asked before:
[How to store and read RegEx raw strings from pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54522826/how-to-store-and-read-regex-raw-strings-from-pandas-dataframe?noredirect=1#comment95853447_54522826)

Comment: Is there an issue with removing all of the double quotes in your dataframe before doing the regex? Are they necessary at all?

Comment: Hi Edeki, I do not add the double quotes. They are added when I store regex in dataframe.

Comment: So before you do the re.findall use the replace method to remove all double quotes from the column/list that contains this data.

Comment: I tried the replace method with no luck.

Comment: Can you post your script and not the partial script? It is impossible to know if you are doing anything correctly without showing the code.

Comment: It would not be helpful because the script is so long. I am sure that the issue is with re.findall. Sorry.

Comment: You do not need to post the entire script, just a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can test and debug your code. If you cannot post the code how can you expect anyone to help you? Please read how to properly ask questions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem which can be summarised as follows:

I tried to store RegEx expressions in HDF5 without wrapping them with `r'...'`, but when I then extracted them from HDF5 via pandas dataframe, they were not treated as raw strings so I could not use them in `re.findall`. Instead, I used the double escape backslash as shown below:

```
pattern_they = '([\\u0621-\\u064a]+\\u0647\\u0645|\\b\\u0647\\u0645)\\b'
```

However, when I extracted RegEx from the pandas dataframe, I got something like:

```
pattern_they_imported ='([\\\\u0621-\\\\u064a]+\\\\u0646\\\\u0627|\\\\b\\\\u0646\\\\u062D\\\\u0646)\\\\b'
```

Therefore, I used `replace` with `re.findall` which works! (I got a list of three elements, which is correct as explained in my question post above):

```
print(re.findall(pattern_they_imported.replace('\\\\', '\\'), mytext))
```

I wonder why the double escape backslash turned to a four escape backslash in the RegEx that I extracted from the pandas dataframe. Anyways, my solution works, which is the most important thing to me.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I find Arabic hard to read and therefore to debug. In general, you could do sth. like the following:

```
import re

mytext = "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"

pattern = r'\b(ipsum)\b'
rx_new = r'{}'.format(pattern)

print(re.findall(rx_new, mytext))
```

Which will correctly yield `['ipsum']`.
You'd need to add the raw-flag here as well.  Question remains: why?

Comment: Thank you for your help. When I read the RegEx from pandas dataframe, I actually get something like:  `pattern = "r'\b(ipsum)\b'"`. That why I posted my question. Now if you use the new pattern with double quotes in your code, `re.findall` would not give a correct outcome. In other words, when I read RegEx from pandas dataframe, I do not get a raw string, but I get a normal string which includes `r'` as characters.